# Python raises AttributeError when attempting to send ARP request on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, scapy

I'm working on a program that automatically scans the local network using ARP requests on a Raspberry Pi 3. The code works fine on my computer, but when I try to run it on my Raspberry Pi, it fails with the following error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/base_classes.py", 
line 241, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: who_has
```

The code that raises this error is as follows:

```
from scapy import *

result, unanswered = sr(ARP(op=ARP.who_has, psrc="192.168.0.79", pdst="192.168.0.1"), timeout=3)
```

Comment: if you run pip freeze on your computer and the RPi, do they come back with the same version of scapy?  That looks like versions changed API's type issue

Comment: "pip freeze | grep scapy" on my computer returns
scapy==2.3.3
scapy-python3==0.26

The same command on the Raspberry Pi returns
scapy===git-archive.dev1e5315539

Comment: I didn't have internet access on my Raspberry Pi, so I had to download the files with my computer, send them over to the Raspberry Pi and install them manually

Comment: Is there a way to install the same version of scapy onto my RPi without having internet access on that RPi?

Comment: Ok never mind that last comment, I got scapy 2.3.3 installed on my RPi, but the error is still there.

Comment: Oddly, Python outputs "git-archive.dev1e5315539" when I run "scapy.VERSION" in a python terminal, yet scapy shows version 2.3.3 when I run "pip freeze | grep scapy". I'm gonna try resetting my RPi and reinstalling everything. I may have done something wrong while installing scapy the first time. I'll post my results

Comment: You were right. The error was caused because of the different versions. I needed scapy 2.3.3 on my RPi and for some reason it wouldn't simply uninstall so I could get the correct version. After resetting my RPi completely and installing scapy 2.3.3 it worked properly and the code runs without errors now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was caused because my RPi had a different version of scapy installed and, for some reason, it would not uninstall that version. After resetting my RPi completely and installing the correct version of scapy (2.3.3), the code now runs fine.

Thank you Foon for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Yeah note that `scapy-python3` is an outdated fork. You needed todo `pip uninstall scapy-python3` then `pip install scapy` (also use scapy 2.4.0, it’s more up to date)

Answer (score 2):

I've also encountered the same problem (I'm using `scapy 2.4.4`),
so here is another solution that might work for some of you:

I've just solved it by coding `op="who-has"` instead of `op=ARP.who_has`.

```
from scapy import *

result, unanswered = sr(ARP(op="who-has", psrc="192.168.0.79", pdst="192.168.0.1"), timeout=3)
```